# два декоратора не работают вместе

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Обрабатывается только первый декоратор, почему - не пойму...

```
def exclamationMark(func):
    def wrapper(func):
        return  func + '!'
    return wrapper

def decor(func):
    def wrapper(func):
        return  func + ' kurwa'
    return wrapper

@exclamationMark
@decor
def kurwa(name):
    return name


print(kurwa(input('kto kurwa? ')).title())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
def exclamationMark(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs) + '!'
    return wrapper

def decor(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs) + ' kurwa'
    return wrapper

@exclamationMark
@decor
def kurwa(name):
    return name


print(kurwa('Test'))  # Test kurwa!
```

---

**UPD.** Спасибо **Xander** за хорошее и подробное объяснение :)

А если отвечать на вопрос "почему не работает"?

> Если по-простому, то враппер подменяет собой декорируемую функцию.
>   Соответственно, он будет вызываться с тем же набором аргументов, с
>   которым вызывается декорируемая функция. Если декорируемая функция
>   принимает name - то и враппер должен принимать name. А если мы заранее
>   не знаем, какой набор аргументов будет принимать декорируемая функция,
>   и хотим универсального решения - то мы используем args и kwargs.

Comment: А если отвечать на вопрос "почему не работает"? :)

Comment: вот и я не совсем пойму на кой нужны args/kwargs, ибо сначала должна же отработать декорируемая функция, а потом её результат берут декораторы по очереди. и почему тогда без args/kwargs отрабатывал только один декоратор????

Comment: @Ljil а как Вы передаете в декоратор параметры декорируемой функции, задумайтесь :)

Comment: Если по-простому, то враппер подменяет собой декорируемую функцию. Соответственно, он будет вызываться с тем же набором аргументов, с которым вызывается декорируемая функция. Если декорируемая функция принимает name - то и враппер должен принимать name. А если мы заранее не знаем, какой набор аргументов будет принимать декорируемая функция, и хотим универсального решения - то мы используем args и kwargs.

Comment: **Почему не работает?**
Потому что вы не вы не вызываете функцию

Comment: @Xander, так прикол в том, что один из двух декораторов то срабатывал)